# Creating a Pivot Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this VBA code for creating a Pivot Table (converted it from a Macro, actually).

```
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim field As PivotField

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rngSource = Summary.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set wsTarget = PivotTable

wsTarget.Select
For Each pt In wsTarget.PivotTables
    pt.Delete
Next pt

Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngSource, xlPivotTableVersion15)
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(wsTarget.Range("A3"), "PivotTable1", , xlPivotTableVersion15)

Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("A")
field.Orientation = xlColumnField
field.Position = 1
field.LayoutBlankLine = True

Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("B")
field.Orientation = xlRowField
field.Position = 1

Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TOTAL")
Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField(field, "Sum of TOTAL", xlSum)
field.NumberFormat = "_ $ * #,##0.00_ "

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The code crashes at the `Set pc` line.

I tried googling, and all of the results were identical to my code.

I'm working with Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

try this..i think you are directly referring the sheet name..

```
Set rngSource = Sheets("Summary").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set wsTarget = sheets("PivotTable")
```

Comment: I did it, but it still doesn't work.. it seems like the rngSource can't get the value of the whole table..
is there another way to insert the table range to the variable?

Thank You!!

Comment: Upload the attachment somewhere. send me the link .. i ll work on it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lcol As Long
Dim rngSource As Range

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rngSource = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lrow, lcol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Way late but did you have a header row?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff196678.aspx